# return to function instead of "0" or "variable "

Tags: c

This is a theoretical question. To understand further how a return statement at the end of a function can be manipulated.

Can we do like this:

```
int intialize1()
{
    ...do smth;
    ...do smth;

    return initialize2();
}
```

in other c file

```
int initialize2()
{
   ...do other thing;
   ...do other thing;

   return 0;
}
```

Is this a proper way to do like this?

Comment: If the syntax is correct, then yes. I.e. the methods return what they say they will return. So `initialize1()` would be `int initialize1()` and `initialize2()` would be `int initialize2()`.

Comment: A function definition with no explicit return type defaults to returning `int` in C90 and earlier, and is illegal in C99 and later. Did you use that obsolete form intentionally? Also, it's not entirely clear from your question just what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes this is correct. This pattern is usually followed by programmers.

Comment: _Return to function_ is a little bit unclear. Are you attempting to return the **return value of another function**? Or are you returning the **reference to another function**? Based on everyone's comment, it seems to be the former.

Comment: People understand *return to function* as returning to the calling function

Comment: I am working on a lengthy program that need to initialize multiple systems states which are somehow "interconnected". First initialize function will follow by initialize2 function upon then ending. Hope my explanation can make it abit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is completely correct, frequently done, and functionally equivalent to:

```
int initialize1()
{
    ...do smth;
    ...do smth;

    int x_value;              // Create a place to store the return value
    x_value = initialize2();  // Get the result of the function, and store it.
    return x_value;           // Return the stored value.
}
```

Comment: Great! Alternative equivalent suggestion does help to give more insight on the usage of return statement.

Answer (score 2):

it is perfectly legal to call function from return statement, 
but you have to make sure that return types of both functions are consistent and
there are no data truncation or semantically wrong implicit conversion

Comment: Thanks @dolphinden, I am confident in using this method now. I have corrected the return type, my bad.